# JSON to dimensional array

Tags: json

I'm trying to convert this JSON:

```
{
 "labels": ["time", "free", "used", "cached", "buffers"],
    "data": [
      [1478635365, 26.91797, 460.9844, 479.3906, 5.80859]
  ]
}
```

to `var['time'] = 1478635365, var['free'] = 26.91797 ...`

Can you help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. 
Then you know what we expect from questioners: showing us the code on where you stuck solving the task by yourself and explaining why you fail to complete the task. Sorry, but Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the *dict comprehension* expression to create `var` dict using `zip()` as:

```
>>> my_json = { "labels": ["time", "free", "used", "cached", "buffers"], "data": [ [ 1478635365, 26.91797, 460.9844, 479.3906, 5.80859] ] }

>>> var = {k: v for k, v in zip(my_json["labels"], my_json["data"][0])}
```

Now you may access the values from `var` dict as:

```
>>> var["time"]
1478635365
>>> var["free"]
26.91797
```